# C# Polygon name does not exists, although it is assigned

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-phone-8, polygon

I am trying to change the color of a polygon in c# for WP8.1
in de XAML i have this code:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Polygon x:Name="topupvote"  Points="20,0 40,30, 0,30" Stroke="White" Fill="White"       Tap="Upvote_Tap" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Rating}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}"/>
    <Polygon x:Name="topdownvote"  Points="20,30 40,0, 0,0"  Stroke="White" Fill="White" Tap="Downvote_Tap" />
</StackPanel>
```

As you see, I named my polygons,
But when I change the name in mainpage.xaml.cs, it says that the name does not exists:

```
private void Upvote_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        topupvote.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);            
    }
```

Comment: Thats weird, but you can reach it using the sender, like: ((Polygon)sender).Fill

Comment: is it inside a resource?

Comment: using the sender has worked